# Trigger event when application wide settings changed

Tags: .net, wpf

How can I trigger an event when application wide setting changed.
For example I need to fire an event when **Properties.Settings.Default.ShowBrushes** changed to true

Comment: Checkout [application setting events](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SettingEvents.aspx) about capturing events that affect application settings. Hope it helps